# Problem in class when use dictionary: AttributeError: 'My_Data' object has no attribute 'Other'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, dictionary

When i run this script, I get an error in the `My_Dictionary[row[0]].Other.append(row[3])` row.

The problem certainly concerns the classes, because this code works correctly if: i use it without the Page1 class, but using only the My_Data class (without self in **init**). Thank you

The error is this:

```
AttributeError: 'My_Data' object has no attribute 'Other'
```

How can I fix? Thank you

```
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, other, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.configure(bg='white')

        class My_Data():
            def __init__(self, Name, Year, Other):
                self.Name: str
                self.Year: float
                self.Other: float
                
        def function1(self):
            My_Dictionary = {}
            x = cursor.execute("sql")

            for row in x.fetchall():
                if row[0] not in My_Dictionary:
                    Data = My_Data(
                        Name=row[1],
                        Year=row[2],
                        Other=list())

                    My_Dictionary[row[0]] = info
                My_Dictionary[row[0]].Other.append(row[3])
```

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `self.Other: float`, exactly what do you think this means? What effect do you expect it to have? In particular, do you think it will cause the `self` to have an accessible `Other`? If so, **what do you think its value will be, and why**? Where should that value come from?

Answer (score 2):

In 'My_Data', I don't see any variable definitions, but some unexpected syntax involving colons and data types. Consider the following code snippet:

```py
self.Other = Other
```

EDIT: here's a full example:

```py
class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, other, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        self.configure(bg='white')

        class My_Data():
            def __init__(self, Name: str, Year: float, Other: float):
                self.Name = Name
                self.Year = Year
                self.Other = Other 
               
        def function1(self):
            My_Dictionary = {}
            x = cursor.execute("sql")

            for row in x.fetchall():
                if row[0] not in My_Dictionary:
                    Data = My_Data(
                        Name=row[1],
                        Year=row[2],
                        Other=list())

                    My_Dictionary[row[0]] = info
                My_Dictionary[row[0]].Other.append(row[3])
```

Comment: In the `__init__` of `My_Data` class.

Comment: In the __init__ of My_Data class there is self.Other: float. I need float. How can I write?

Comment: Can you be more specific please? A thousand thanks

Comment: Try `def __init__(self, Name: str, Year:float, Other:float): self.name = name` etc.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg You are kind, but your code is confusing me. If I follow your suggestion, then what should I write in self.name, self.year and self.other? You have example you wrote self.name = name, but if you are really sure? Thank you

Comment: That was a mistype. See the code in the answer below.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg It just prints the key (is row[0]) correctly, then I get these: <x.NameFile.Page1.__init__.<locals>.My_Data object at 0x7f25d3ec5690>,

Comment: How do you get this? There are no `print` in your code?

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I'm going to sleep now. I hope you can come up with some good ideas to fix the problem and edit your answer, otherwise thanks anyway for your kindness. I will read tomorrow. Soon

Comment: I posted the answer below. Please comment it. I will read your comments tomorrow.

Comment: I added a full example that shows how you can implement this change.

Comment: It's not "weird syntax"; those are just (mostly) meaningless variable annotations.